# On Deuteronomy 28:23, Rashi says copper is "mazi'a". What does this mean?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, words, translation, rashi, ki-tavo

I have this question on Rashi every year in Ki Savo. [Deuteronomy 28:23](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9992/showrashi/true#v2823) says: "And the heavens above your head will be like copper and the earth that is beneath you, iron."
Rashi says that the heavens will be “*mazi’in*” as copper is “*mazi’a*” and as a result there will not be destruction (*avadon*) through dryness (*chorev*) in the world (my translation). What does Rashi mean? How is copper “mazi’a” in a way that iron is not?

Comment: here is the archive of that site, which renders it 'sweats'. Dave's answer, below, seems right. http://web.archive.org/web/20090619193836/http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9992/showrashi/true

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This site](http://www.tzura.co.il/TSHSD/yezira.asp?codyezira=5400) argues, somewhat convincingly (based on Rashi and Maharsha), that the reference is to the patina (oxides) that emerges on the surface of copper. Iron in those days always had a layer of rust, and therefore was not considered to "sweat" any kind of substance.

Comment: Thank you. What is the function of www.tzura.co.il?

Comment: Seems to be a site where people can submit articles and poetry.